# Regex Pattern Matching Concatenationn

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, visual-studio-2013, string-concatenation

I am trying to find some patterns of coding style in my solution. The use case is that I have to replace all the string concatenation with `StringBuilder` in razor and find all string concatenation in `JavaScript`. I am finding it very difficult to get all such code lines which have string concatenation in the following 2 ways.

```
1) str = str+str2+str3+"str4 " etc;
2) str+=str2+str3+"str4 " etc;
```

I tried using finding tool of VS 2013 and searched with character `+`, I got hell lot of lines. Please help me the reg ex pattern for above 2 styles of code lines, so at least number of lines will reduce. I am finding it difficult to get Reg Ex for above 2 styles of code.

Comment: What's your expected output from those strings ?

Comment: I dont need any output. Some have done concatenation is style 1 and some using 2nd way. I need to use finding(ctrl+f) functionality of VS 2013 and find such code lines. So i can replace them with stringbuilder.

Comment: So the variable name could be anything other than `str` and `str2` ?

Comment: yes. It can be anything but both on LHS and RHS should match.

Comment: When you use shorthand operator **`+=`** there could be only one value on right hand side. `str+=str2+str3+"str4 "` is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
([\w_]+[\w\d]*)(?:\s*=\s*\1{1}\s*\+\s*|\s*\+=\s*)("?[\w_]+[\w\d]*"?)(\s*\+\s*"?([\w_]+[\w\d]*"?))*;
```

Here I assumed that variable may start with an underline or a alphabetic character. You may want to make some changes to it if you need.

https://regex101.com/r/mE9zO7/2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working to some extent. Like it is working for such kind of statements

strCloseHTML = strCloseHTML + PagingControlHTML;

But not working for the following kind of statements

strRowHTML = strRowHTML + "<tr class='gridrow odd action'>";

Comment: Got a question, on the link it says 2 matches, 8293 steps. If we have a large input, will performance be impacted? Should poster go for a *while(readline())* approach?

Comment: ouch you want this to be able to match html code too? that would be lots of trouble doing such a thing with regular expressions. I don't know what you are trying to do. but you are doing it wrong.

Comment: still its not matching 

strRowHTML = strRowHTML + "<tr class='gridrow odd action'>";

Comment: Ok Can you please tell me the RegEx for just matching str=str+ and str+=

Comment: @user2998990 it would be: `([A-Za-z_]\w+)\s*\+?=\s*(\1\+)?`

Comment: Its matching everything. I am getting 21K of lines now. I was avoiding 14K lines

Comment: you mean literal `str+=` and `str=str+`?

Comment: its event matching 

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107220/discussion-between-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani-and-user2998990).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
(\w+ = \w+\+\w)|(\w+\s?\+=\s?\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind the variable naming conventions that variable name can begin with an `_` or `[A-Za-z]` this regex matches all such instances of concatenation.

**Regex:** `([A-Za-z_]\w+)\s*\+?=\s*(\1\s*)?(\+?\s*(([A-Za-z_]\w+)|"?.*?"?))*;`

**Explanation:**

- `([A-Za-z_]\w+)` matches the variable name starting with `_` or `[A-Za-z]` followed by any character from `word` class.
- `\s*\+?` Optional `whitespace` and `+` to match **shorthand concatenation operator**.
- `\s*(\1\s*)?` If shorthand operator is not used then this will match conventional way of concatenating.
- `(\+?\s*(([A-Za-z_]\w+)|"?.*?"?))*` succeeding variable names which **must** be present. These could be **zero or many**. This could also be a literal string like `"hello world"` and also matches **HTML data**.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sE3bG8/4)**

Comment: Its is not matching any of the following code lines

strCloseHTML = strCloseHTML + PagingControlHTML;
strRowHTML = strRowHTML + "<tr class='gridrow odd action'>";

Comment: @user2998990: You didn't mentioned that you wish to match HTML code too. **When you edit a question, add the EDIT title**. Otherwise answers which worked for your previous version of question might not work for added parts and people will down vote them as **Not useful**

Comment: I am sorry. But string can be anything in this case.